# Drawing Lines inside 3D Plots

Tags: tikz-3dplot

In the following spiral, I would like to draw a line from $(3,0,0)$ to $(3,0,4)$ which I would normally do quite simply with \draw[black, thick] (3,0,0) -- (3,0,4);

However the line will not get drawn. Any help would be appreciated, my code is as below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=1.2]
    \begin{axis}[view={125}{25},
     axis lines=center,axis on top,
     xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,
     xtick={10},ytick={10},ztick={10},
     xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5,zmin=-1,zmax=7,
     enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
     
     \addplot3+[no markers,line width=0.75pt, black,samples=400, samples y=0,domain=0:4,variable=\t, red]
                                      ({3*cos(deg(2*pi*\t))},{3*sin(deg(2*pi*\t))},{\t});
    \draw[] (3,0,0) -- (3,0,4);
    \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: what is redgraph - shows an error

Comment: `\draw[blue] (axis cs: 3,0,0) -- (axis cs: 3,0,4);`  (axis cs:  ...) is normally the default, but evidently not for 3D coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple:
Just use `\addplot` instead of draw:

```
\addplot3+[draw=blue, no markers,line width=0.75pt] coordinates {(3,0,0) (3,0,4)};
```

Like John Kormylo pointed out, `axis cs` also works and might be considered the better match for your question:

```
\draw[blue, line width=0.75pt] (axis cs: 3,0,0) -- (axis cs: 3,0,4);
```

Both yield:

[image: Solution]

**FYI**: You did not actually provide a M**W**E (the w stands for working ;). You get faster and better help, if you provide a fully working (e.g. just by copy-and-paste) example. This is what I used instead:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.0cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[view={125}{25},
             axis lines=center,axis on top,
             xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5,zmin=-1,zmax=7,
             enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
 
             \addplot3+[no markers,line width=0.75pt, black,samples=400, samples y=0,domain=0:4,variable=\t, color=red]
                ({3*cos(deg(2*pi*\t))},{3*sin(deg(2*pi*\t))},{\t});
            \draw[] (3,0,0) -- (3,0,4);
        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]